# Automatically returning after a command

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt

I'd like to have return pressed twice after I run a command to make the terminal easier to read.

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sda1
Disk /dev/sda1: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
[root@localhost ~]# RETURN
[root@localhost ~]# RETURN
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sda1
Disk /dev/sda1: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
[root@localhost ~]# RETURN
[root@localhost ~]# RETURN
[root@localhost ~]# NEW COMMAND
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Add a couple of `\n`s to the start of your PS1 environment variable: `export PS1="\n\n$PS1"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing return twice will do that, but that is not really what you want.

Try the following:

```
$ export PS1="\n\n$PS1"
```

If you want to do this for yourself, edit `.profile` in your homedirectory. If you want to do this system wide, put it in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: If I wanted to remove a newline from $PS1, what would I have to edit? I tried deleting one of the \n from the answer, but that just added another newline.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. How would I make this change permanent? I'd like every shell session to include a \n in my PS1 variable.